# Creating raster/DEM that represents pre-landslide morphology using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geology

I've posted something similar here before, but my previous post did not yield great results.

I am a Master student in Geology studying landslides. For a part of my project I need to calculate the volume of a several prehistoric landslide deposits. Most of the papers I have found so far discuss landslides deposits which have occurred relatively recently and have the benefit of some kind of pre-slide topography, satellite image, interpolated GPR, or some other kind of DEM, making the cut-and-fill method (ArcMap) for calculating volume fairly straight forward. Since the slides I'm looking at are all at least 1000 years old, there is no satellite imagery or topo. map to pull from.

Fortunately I do have access to an excellent Lidar dataset in my study area for the post-event DEM, but my issues arise when trying to construct a pre-event raster/DEM. Specially I'm looking for a step-by-step guide on how to do this (my ArcGIS skills are subpar at best) so I can insert my custom pre-event DEM into the cut-and-fill tool. I understand that I essentially just need to create a DEM that represents what the topography probably looked like before the landslide; I just don't know how to do this for ArcGIS.

I will have to calculate both the volume of the debris field and the volume of the source zone (depletion zone).

(1) Volume of debris field

Since these landslides are all located in a river valley, there are river terrace deposits which are relatively flat. The terraces can be used to get an idea of the pre-event topography. They appear well on LiDAR but my problem is accounting for small elevation changes from terraces further upstream and those downstream. I am not sure how to create a slightly tilted DEM that would represent a pre-event river terrace.

(2) Volume of source zone

Second is calculating the void space or the amount of material that was released during the landslide event. The hollows are fairly evident when looking at LiDAR, and theoretically I would just "drape" a DEM over the void space like holding a sheet taut over the hollow.

The best paper I have found so far (https://www.nat-hazards-earth-syst-sci.net/18/709/2018/) mentions "the depleted area was manually filled by inserting several linearly aligned points within the slide area" (section 4.2 in results). I just don't know enough about ArcGIS to figure this part out.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.